Finding the closest date in Excel
I have a spreadsheet with two sheets, They both have two columns: ID and Inspection Date.
I want to:

Look at the first sheet for a row with a specific ID (xxxxx) and Date (x/xx/xxxx).

Then, look at the second sheet to find matches with the same ID (xxxxx).

Of all the resulting dates, find the one that is immediately before x/xx/xxxx.



Hey, are you looking for one input or all values in ID, Date columns in the first sheet?

@nkalvi all values

You can use FILTER function for this to find all the dates that their ID match the ID in Sheet2 with dates before x/xx/xxxx. Then use MAX to find the closest match:
=MAX(FILTER(Sheet2!B:B, (Sheet2!A:A=A2)*(Sheet2!B:B<B2)))

Where A2 and B2 are ID and Date in the first tab.
In case there are no matches, IFERROR can be used to handle it:
=IFERROR(MAX(FILTER(Sheet2!B:B, (Sheet2!A:A=A2)*(Sheet2!B:B<B2))), "No Match")

This will return No Match if there are no matches.

yes but in the solution where are you referencing the ID and date from Sheet 1?

It is A2 for the ID and B2 for the date.

Sheet 1 has A2:A900 with ID and B2:B900 with dates.  Sheet 2 has A1:A3000 with ID and B1:B3000 with dates.  I want to start by matching A2 in Sheet 1 with all of the same IDs in A in Sheet 2.  I'll have many matches.  I want to look at all the results of Column B in Sheet 2 find the one closest before the date in B2 and place it in C2

this is best approach I've seen so far (better than mine)

Then you need to write that formula in C2 and downwards (assuming you want all the results of column B in sheet 2 that also match the A2 in Sheet 1)

Because you are putting the formula in Sheet1, so you don't need to reference the current sheet. If you are in Sheet1, then A2 and Sheet1!A2 are the same.

Thanks - works great (except if there are not matches I get a #CALC error - how can I update the formula to account for this.  Not sure where to put a ,0

Updated to handle the "no match" case

Below/here refer:
    =LET(
w_,INDEX(C3:C8,MATCH(11111,B3:B8,0))+N("sht2, dates with same ID"),
x1_,SORT(FILTER(G3#,--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(11111,F3#))),,1)+N("necessary sort for type of match requested"),
y_,INDEX(x1_,MATCH(w_,x1_,1)) +N("voila!"),
y_)



Of greater interest to me, perhaps, would be the scenario of multiple dates matching 11111 in Sht1. Possible?


Yes @JB-007 there will be duplicates of the ID in both sheets.  And I see the solution references a hard ID - was looking for something referencing cells

Just replace the hard coded (that appeared in OTP example if I recall) with cell reference surely, no?

If you have Microsoft 365, you could try this:
=LET(
    ids_1, A2:A5,
    dates_1, B2:B5,
    dates_2, Sheet2!B1:B17,
    ids_2, Sheet2!A1:A17,
    date_before, LAMBDA(id_1, date_1,
        TAKE(
            SORT(FILTER(dates_2, (ids_2 = id_1) * (dates_2 < date_1), ""), , -1),
            1
        )
    ),
    MAP(ids_1, dates_1, date_before)
)

To automatically include up to the last non-blank cells, you could replace the variables like this:
    ids_1, A2:XLOOKUP(TRUE, A:A <> "", A:A, , , -1),
    dates_1, B2:XLOOKUP(TRUE, B:B <> "", B:B, , , -1),
    ids_2, Sheet2!A1:XLOOKUP(TRUE, Sheet2!A:A <> "", Sheet2!A:A, , , -1),
    dates_2, Sheet2!B1:XLOOKUP(TRUE, Sheet2!B:B <> "", Sheet2!B:B, , , -1),


